# SQL Alchemy User <-> Customer relationship, many to one, returns wrong value

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I'm trying to create a many to one relationship for a database model where multiple users can exist under one customer.

My code all works within the app but recently I realized when I added a new user record, the relationship returns the wrong customer record based on the relationship.

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('customer.id'),default=None)
    aws_sub = Column(String(50),unique=True)
    email = Column(String(120), unique=True)
    status = Column(Boolean, unique=False,default=False)
    access_token = Column(String(2500))
    refresh_token = Column(String(2500))
    id_token = Column(String(2500))
    resend_code = Column(String(32))
    date_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    date_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
    
    customer = relationship("Customer", uselist=False, back_populates="users",foreign_keys=[customer_id],remote_side=customer_id)



class Customer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    #False is trial account
    status = Column(Boolean, unique=False,default=False)
    #primary_user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), unique=True)
    date_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    date_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
    setup_complete = Column(Boolean, unique=False,default=False)
    setup_step = Column(Integer, default=1)

    users = relationship("User", uselist=False, back_populates="customer")
    tickets = relationship("Ticket", uselist=False, back_populates="customer")
    api = relationship("API", backref="Customer")
```

I have two users in the database stored with this model and when I try to retrieve the record on 2nd user record, who does not have a customer_id set (NULL), it incorrectly retrieves the customer_id 1, which is for the first user. There is only one record in the customer table, which corresponds to the first user. The second user has no associated customer record. Shouldn't the customer relationship for the user return null or None?

I'm trying to avoid initializing the parts of the data that aren't needed until they are necessary so the logic only works if data is expected, otherwise it will implicitly fail. The reason I need users AND customers is because I want my application to eventually support multiple user accounts but initially most user accounts will be tied to one "customer" or company account.

I'm using current_user.customer is some of my views with Flask and Flask-login so I want to make sure my views handle null cases or "relationship not yet established".

Users data:

| id | customer_id | aws_sub | email | status | access_token | refresh_token | id_token | resend_code | date_created | date_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | q34tq34tq34t3q4t | jandoe@yahoo.com | True | xxx... | zzz... | yyy... | xxxx | 2021-05-20 04:27:01 | 2021-05-30 14:37:04 |
| 2 | NULL | q34tq34tq34t | jsmith@yahoo.com | True | xxx... | xxxxx... | yyy... | zzz | 2021-06-04 16:50:00 | 2021-06-04 16:50:46 |

Customer table:

| id | name | status | date_created | date_updated | setup_complete | setup_step |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Contoso | False | 2021-05-21 03:21:56 | 2021-05-25 02:16:42 | True | NULL |

Comment: Can you share the query?

Comment: There's no query, the current_user variable returns the current user model from Flask-login module. I can update the post to include some of the data if it helps context.

Comment: I updated and added the data, maybe it will help with the context? I'm logged into jsmith, who has no customer table so I prefer to return None if I try to access the customer for that user model. However it instead retrieves the first customer record, which is tied to jandoe.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this. I was passing back_populates on both sides of the model since this is a bi-directional many to one (User -> Customer) relationship. However it seems you can do this by only specifying relationship from one side using backref, in this case:

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    ....
    users = relationship("User", uselist=False, backref="customer")
```

I commented out the existing relationship I had in the many side (user model) and current_user.customer now returns null if the customer_id for that user is null. I remember seeing somewhere that back_populates was newer so I guess I assumed that it was preferred...